# How to collect a Value out of multiple div elements in a list with Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a list on a website that stores the part number and the order number.
in this list are different div elements and i would like to export every part number in this list.

The list looks like this:

```
<div class="spareValue">
    <span class="label">OrderNumber:</span>
    <span class="PartNumber">180011</span>
</div>
<div class="spareValue">
    <span class="label">SparePartNumber:</span>
    <span class="PartNumber">01002523</span>
</div>
```

How can i export every OrderNumber and put them into a list in c# that i can work with the values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lot of ways to do that:

```
        var spans = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.spareValue span"));
        var nbrspans = spans.Count;
        var Listordernumber = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nbrspans; i +=2)
        {
            if (spans[i].GetAttribute("textContent") != "OrderNumber:") continue;
            Listordernumber.Add(spans[i + 1].GetAttribute("textContent"));
        }
```

so Listordernumber contains the result

if you prefer linq, you could use that:

```
string path = "//div[@class='spareValue' and ./span[text()='OrderNumber:']]/span[@class = 'PartNumber']";
var Listordernumber = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(path)).Select(s => s.GetAttribute("textContent")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oke, you want every partnummer, that belongs to an ordernummer. That leads me to this xPath, find the div that has a ordernumber in it, than find the partnumber element inside.
Then to find them all (or none).
Last put them all in a neat list, selecting the partnumber text:

```
string path = "//div[@class='spareValue' and ./span[text()='OrderNumber:']]/div[@class='PartNumber']"
var elements = driver.findElements(By.XPath(path));
var listOrderNumber = elements.Select(e=>e.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var els = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[text()='OrderNumber:']"));

foreach(var el in els){
var el = els.FindElement(By.XPath("./../span[@class='PartNumber']"));
console.writeline("OrderNumber: "+el.Text());
}
```

first, you have to find all elements that have "OrderNumber:" text on it and eliminate all elements that don't.

now, iterate through all elements that have "OrderNumber:" we have found from step above and go to its parent node, then find all element inside the parent node that the class name is "PartNumber".